# Where are the glyphicons stored in Visual Studio MVC5?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5, glyphicons

VS2013 update 5, MVC5

I'm able to use glyphicons but not every one of the presumably free glyphicons come up.  I read a great many posts but thought before I do anything to my IDE I better ask for some help.  We often start changing things without knowing why, and it causes other problems.

I'm able to display the **glyphicon-shopping-cart** from inside a standard MVC5 templated project; **glyphicon-shopping-cart** shows up in intellisense.  But there is not an intellisense entry for **glyphicon-shopping-cart-in** or **glyphicon-shopping-cart-out**.

So I downloaded the free glyphicon file and it includes both cart-in and cart-out.  But I don't understand where I would place those files in Visual Studio for use.

Hence my question "Where are the glyphicons stored" so I can add extra ones to that location.  Or is it some special setup that is not easily added to?

Comment: Have you tried specifying *glyphicon-shopping-cart-in* or *glyphicon-shopping-cart-out* despite these not showing up in Intellisense?  Maybe they are present but not in Intellisense for other reasons?

Comment: Yes.  Actually, that was how I found out I'm not able to access the glyphicon-shopping-cart-in/out images.  Intellisence in Razor only seems to work when using simpler syntax such as <a class="...">, but when I add htmlAttributes:=New With {class = "..."} in an html helper intellisense doesn't function, so it wasn't until the page displayed without the icons that I started looking for it using <a class="...">.